# Program would neither execute or terminate

Tags: java, output

After trying out a few ways to fix my code from an arrayindexoutofbound exception, there's one way it wouldn't produce the exception, however the program would not output anything like it should, it would not throw exceptions or errors, and it shows that the program is not terminated. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class treez {

final Scanner in;
 public treez()
 {
     in=new Scanner(System.in);
     run();
     in.close();

 }
 public void run()
 {
     System.out.println("Enter normal restaurant numbers and pho restaurant numbers");
     final String input=in.nextLine();
     final int[] rest=createarray(input);
     final int normal=rest[0];
     final int pho=rest[1];
     final String input1=in.nextLine();
     final int[] phoresspecific=createarray(input1);
     Arrays.sort(phoresspecific);
     boolean[][] matrix;
     matrix=new boolean[normal][normal];
     for(int i=0;i<normal;i++)
     {
         for(int j=0;j<normal;j++)
         {
             matrix[i][j]=false;
         }
     }
     int[] total=new int[normal];

     for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++) matrix[i]=new boolean[normal];
     for(int i=0;i<normal;i++)
     {
         total[i]=i;
         total[i]=Arrays.binarySearch(total, i);
     }
     Arrays.sort(total);
     for(int i=0 ; i < normal - 1; i++) {
         int x = 0;
         int y = 0;
         String ans = in.nextLine();
         int[] arraya = createaarray(ans);
         x = arraya[0];
         y = arraya[1];
         matrix[x][y]= true;
         matrix[y][x]=true;
     }
     in.close();
     int answer=decisions(pho,matrix,phoresspecific,normal);
     System.out.println(answer);
 }
 private int decisions(int pho, boolean matrix[][],int[] phoresspecific,int normal)
 {
     int steps=0;
     if(pho==2)
     {
         for(int j=0;j<normal-1;j++)
         {
             for(int i=phoresspecific[0];i<normal-1;i++)
             {
                 if(matrix[j][i]==true)
                 {
                     j++;
                     steps++;
                     if(j==phoresspecific[1]) break;
                 }
             }
             if(j==phoresspecific[1]) break;
         }
     }
     else
     {
         int counter=0;
         int[] step=new int[pho-1];
         for(int j=0;j<pho-1;j++)
         {
             counter=0;
             for(int i=0;i<normal-1;i++)
             {
                 for(int l=phoresspecific[j];l<normal-1;l+=0)
                 {
                     if(matrix[i][l]==true)
                     {
                         i++;
                         step[j]++;
                         if(i==j)
                         {
                             counter++;
                         }

                     }
                 }
                 if(counter==pho) break;
             }
         }
         Arrays.sort(step);
         steps=step[0];
     }
     steps--;
     return(steps);
 }
 private int[] createarray(final String input)
 {
     final String[] args=input.trim().split("\\s+");
     final int[] list=new int[2];
     for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
         list[i]=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

     return list;
 }
 private int[] createaarray(final String ans)
 {
     final String[] args=ans.trim().split("\\s+");
     final int[] list=new int[2];
     for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
         list[i]=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

     return list;
 }

 public static void main(String args[])
 {

    new treez();
 }
}
```

From the previous mistakes, I believe the error is either in line 83 or 85, which are:

```
 for(int l=phoresspecific[j];l<normal-1;l+=0)
                 {
                     if(matrix[i][l]==true)
```

in

```
 for(int l=phoresspecific[j];l<normal-1;l+=0)
                 {
                     if(matrix[i][l]==true)
                     {
                         i++;
                         step[j]++;
                         if(i==j)
                         {
                             counter++;
                         }

                     }
                 }
```

With input:

```
8 5
0 6 4 3 7
0 1
0 2
2 3
4 3
6 1
1 5
7 3
```

The program would neither produce an output or terminate. Help would be appreciated.
Edit:the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
at treez.decisions(treez.java:85)
at treez.run(treez.java:52)
at treez.<init>(treez.java:9)
at treez.main(treez.java:127)
```

Edit2:This program is used to determine the minimum time used for a person to reach all the locations wrote in from input line 2. There's no edge weight since it takes one minute from one place to another. All the lines after second lines states there is a road connecting place a and b.

Comment: please show the stack trace when an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException happens

Comment: Sooo were expected to debug a deeply-nested, completely undocumented method without even having the slightest hint what it does? Please describe what the code does in detail. And btw. usually a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is expected; not the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checkt your build configurations?
And its kind a hard looking for possible errors when you provide not a lot of information about your program.
EDIT: I managed to get it running and can confirm that you program (with your input does not return anything and I didn't step trough every piece of code)
But you always use the "createarray" function, which you have two times implemented and its the same function (exept of the name of the value you pass).
Then you have an infinite loop in this code:

```
   for(int i=0;i<normal-1;i++){
       for(int l=phoresspecific[j];l<normal-1;l+=0){
           if(matrix[i][l]==true){
              i++;
              step[j]++;
              if(i==j) counter++;
           }
       }
     if(counter==pho) break;
   }
```

The inner for-loop doesnt increment its value and is always trying to evaluate the if condition wich will always stay the same due to the never changing index l . That is probably your error.
Another EDIT:
In the second line of your parameters you have more than two values, but your functions always read only two parameters.

Comment: @97hilfel do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @lan I don't habe any idea and I don't really know what you are doing there, but you always check the same condition so maybe you want to increment l by 1 instead of 0 so you dont always cleck the same field of the array.